# How can I include Wordpress posts in a custom PHP file?

Tags: php, wordpress, rss, blogs

This is what i want to do:

I want `/summary.php` to include 5 latest posts (only the extract) from my blog, which lives in `/wp`.

Is there any way to include Wordpress in `/summary.php` and only print the html for these posts? (Maybe i should parse the rss?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look to [Integrating WordPress with your Website](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website)

This is an example from that page, that shows the first ten posts in alphabetical order:

```
<?php
require('/the/path/to/your/wp-blog-header.php');
?>

<?php
$posts = get_posts('numberposts=10&order=ASC&orderby=post_title');
foreach ($posts as $post) : start_wp(); ?>
<?php the_date(); echo "<br />"; ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>    
<?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
<?php
endforeach;
?>
```

Use `$posts = get_posts('numberposts=10');` if you want the 10 latest posts.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest and most elegant way to do this is to create a custom theme to live on summary.php. The WP library exposes a number of functions for easy output of articles.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have answered your self their. The RSS feed will give you the content of your latest posts.

With not much work you can just pull out the data you need

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "clean" template, which you can apply to 'summary' page (this page must be a wordpress page too). 
You can find an example here: 
http://www.tyssendesign.com.au/articles/cms/fetching-posts-in-wordpress-expressionengine-with-jquery-ajax/

Answer (score 0):

you can include wp-config.php, which will pull in the rest of the API. then you will be able to use wp functions like

```
function get_post($postID)
```