# Show wordpress posts outside of the blog

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs

I have two wordpress blogs on my site and now I want to show the posts of categories of both blogs on the home page. I am using the following code.

```
<?php require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/projects/wp-load.php'); 
 query_posts('cat=9& showposts=8');  if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) :   
the_post(); ?>
<ul><li>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php 
$shorttitle4 = substr(the_title('','',FALSE),0,25)."...";

echo $shorttitle4;
?></a>

</li></ul>
<?php endwhile; else: echo "no posts"; endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

One of my blogs is placed in the "projects" folder and another one is placed in "technology folder". but this code is showing the posts only from projects blogs if I changed the folder in as "technology" in the above code. I think this is because of wp-load.php file. Can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is two or more ways, you can do it.

1. Using PHP Pear packages, like XML_RSS, XML_Tree and XML_Parser
2. Using RSS feed

Try RSS feed. Because most of the hosting provider company will not provide packages installed ready server.

write on your theme function file (functions.php)

```
function read_rss($display=0,$url='') {
    $rss = new XML_RSS($url);
    $rss->parse();
    $itemArr = array_slice ( $rss->getItems(), 0, $display );
    return $itemArr;
}
```

Now write on your template file

```
<ul>
< ?php
    $items = read_rss(2,'http://sivel.net/feed');
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        echo '<li><a href="' . $item['link'] . '">' . $item['title'] . '</a>';
    }
?>
</ul>
```

You can do something more than it, follow [this link](http://www.worldoweb.co.uk/2012/display-wordpress-posts-on-another-wp-blog) or check [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515871/how-can-i-include-wordpress-posts-in-a-custom-php-file?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You really need to give more information, but I think it might be because the following query might not be successful in the other folder

```
query_posts('cat=9& showposts=8');
```

Does category 9 exist in the technology site? Perhaps you need to do another query for the other folder?

Comment: i am doing another query for each category from both blogs. but the post are showing only from one blog. nothing is shown from another blog.

Comment: Are you loading the same wp-load for both of them? Because then it will be fetching both of them from the same database. You should make a local file, using the local wp-load.php (in the second project folder) and then include that file where you need it. It should work then!